# How to create a lambda function which triggered by kinesis in another account?

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to create a stack in B account with a cloudformation like this.

```
{
 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
 "Resources": {
"lambda": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": "lambda-test-zwshao",
      "S3Key": "lambda_spike.zip"
    },
    "Description": "lambda spike function..",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::A account:role/kinesis-read",
    "Runtime": "nodejs4.3",
    "Timeout": 20
  }
},
"eventSourceMapping": {
  "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
  "Properties": {
    "BatchSize" : 100,
    "Enabled" : true,
    "EventSourceArn" : "arn:aws:kinesis:ap-southeast-2:A account:stream/lambda-test",
    "FunctionName" : {"Ref": "lambda"},
    "StartingPosition" : "TRIM_HORIZON"
  }
  }
 }
}
```

The A account is the account number.

The error is `Cross-account pass role is not allowed`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-account lambda trigger by kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448960/cross-account-lambda-trigger-by-kinesis)

Answer (score 3):

I asked the `AWS TECH SUPPORT CENTER`. It does not support this currently.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

> **Cross-account access**: Granting access to resources in one account to a
>   trusted principal in a different account is often referred to as
>   cross-account access. Roles are the primary way to grant cross-account
>   access. However, with some of the web services offered by AWS you can
>   attach a policy directly to a resource (instead of using a role as a
>   proxy). These are called resource-based policies, and you can use them
>   to grant principals in another AWS account access to the resource. The
>   following services support resource-based policies for the specified
>   resources: Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) buckets, Amazon Glacier
>   vaults, Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) topics, and Amazon
>   Simple Queue Service (SQS) queues. For more information, see How IAM
>   Roles Differ from Resource-based Policies
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html

This post provides an example of how to enable corss-account access,
https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx70F69I9G8TYG/How-to-enable-cross-account-access-to-the-AWS-Management-Console

However, here's a hacky approach for similar issue
https://gist.github.com/djm/1af7dec88fb24bd73188

Comment: I know we can assume role to access the resource cross account. But it is not helpful to me.